# C# WPF - ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, itemssource

I'm working on a custom control that internally uses a ComboBox.

My problem is when the ComboBox is focused and has the drop-down open, it appears to focus the entire control.  I would like to automatically highlight the first item in the drop drown, but right now you have to push the Down key to do so.

Is there a way to programmatically Highlight the first item in a ComboBox (set the readonly IsHighlighted property to true)?  I believe the concept of IsHighlight within a ComboBox is different than Focus.  Also, I am binding via ItemsSource, so I have no reference to ComboBoxItems.

Comment: So you want the first item highlighted instead of the selected item?

Comment: There is not a selected item at this point.  When the ComboBox is focused and dropdown is open, I need the first ComboBoxItem highlighted so you can use the up/down arrow keys within the dropdown.  Right now you have to hit Down before the first item is highlighted.

Comment: Ah sorry didn't remember combobox doesn't need to have a selected item, I always have :-) Hmm, been looking at it for a while, but can't find a solution. I tried sending key strokes, but even that didn't work...

Comment: Yeah, sending a Down keypress does some crazy stuff that seems to break the IsHighlight logic of the ComboBox.  I'm going to try @Andrei's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it, although it might not cover all the cases - but you didn't provide too many details (for example, what happens when there is already an element selected? Do you still want to select the first element in the list? The code below will highlight the first element only when there is no selection in the combobox. To make it always select the first element, the `DropDownOpened` event should be handled too).

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    combobox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += new EventHandler(ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged);
}

void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (combobox.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        (combobox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ComboBoxItem).Focus();
    }
}
```

(Hope I understood correctly and this is what you want to do).

Comment: This works, I store the ComboBoxItem in a member variable and only call Focus when appropriate.  Only issue now is that if you keep pressing down, the ScrollViewer doesn't automatically scroll.  If I take this code out, the ScrollViewer works as intended.

Comment: When exactly do you press the down key? When the drop-down list is open? I just did a quick test and it seems to work for me, pressing down scrolls without any issues. Maybe your case is more complex than my simple combobox with 100 strings in it?

Comment: My case is a little more complex, I guess.  Though I think I will eventually have it figured out with your solution, I'm marking you as the answer.

Comment: In my final solution, I used your method to grab the generated ComboBoxItem, and then raised the MouseEnter event manually to make it work.  Calling Focus() caused problems in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you are looking for but if you set mycombo.SelectedIndex = 0 then mycombo.IsDropDownOpen = True it should open it up and have the first item selected. It will be highlighted but will also be the value in the combobox as well. I'm not sure if this is not the desired effect though..

Comment: Yeah I don't want the ComboBox to select, just the "focus"/"IsHighlight" to be on the first ComboBoxItem.